# how to write effective wordpress plugin to search using user input via postcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create my own word-press plugin which will allow a user to submit their postcode on a form, this will search a list of postcodes and select a correct area and then divert the user to the webpage with the appropriate area in the URL.

I am struggling to get this to work, and am also worried I may be taking an altogether ridiculous approach, and would appreciate (constructive) advice from somebody with more experience.

I have managed to get all of the postcode data corresponding to area in a table. This is roughly 2 million rows for reference. eg. WD4 5SH - Hartfordshire

The current approach I have tried is to create a plugin which is essentially the one function, it creates the postcode data into an array. It then takes the user input and finds the corresponding area. Finally it uses the header function to redirect to the appropriate URL.

I have tried to test this on instant wordpress, but it has come up with an error of the memory limit being reached. I could possibly try to increase the memory, but I am now worried that this is going to make the website really heavy, and maybe I should be using some sort of database.

To give you a general idea of my level I am moderately comfortable with scripting mostly in Perl and R but new to Wordpress.

My code is essentially:

> Plugin:

```
<?php 
/** 
* Plugin Name: wordpress plugin 
**/ 
function Search_Area_function($post_code) {
$Postcodes = array( "AL1 1AG" => "1", "AL1 1AJ" => "2" );
$AreaKey = array( "1" => "Hertfordshire", "2" => "Bedfordshire");

/* Search array for the core post info, assign number simultaneously */

$currentAreaCode = array_search($post_code, $Postcodes);
$areafound = array_search($currentAreaCode, $AreaKey);

/* redirect to county page  */
header('Location: examplewebsite.com/'.$areafound);
}
?>
```

> Form:

```
<form id="search" action="wordpress_plugin.php" method="get">
<div><input id="s" name="s" type="text" value="Postcode" />     <input   id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="search" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a database `SELECT` to do the search, rather than loading everything into memory?  If you edit your question to show your database table structure for postcodes and areas, I can probably help

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment "maybe I should be using some sort of database", so I now assume the data's not in the database.  That's probably the best place for it.  Is this a plugin you're going to distribute (in which case you'll need to include code to populate the database)?  Or is it just for one specific site, in which case you can populate it manually?

Comment: This is only for my specific site, as I think it's quite a rare use, so I would be happy to populate the database myself. thanks. So far I have not used any databases. I think I could easily set up a mySQL database using my hosting backend services. Your comment has helped enourmously, the select function has helped me find many more useful resources, I just wasn't sure where to start. I think I may be able to get it working from this, and will update later today.

Comment: No problem.  WordPress already uses a MySQL database - create your new tables in there, and select the data using the `$wpdb` object (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).  More than happy to help if you have more questions (though I'm about to go to bed, so don't expect a quick response ;) )